# Ensure every element in array passes asynchronous test

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, mongoose

I've written a function which ensures all objects in the `items` array belong to the `user`. This involves a database check, which results in the code being asynchronous. This code works, but feels sloppy. I'd appreciate a review and suggestions for how to improve it.

The main challenge I had with writing this was to use items.every() with Promises and I don't think the solution I came up with was very elegant. I spent quite a bit of time on it and couldn't think of a better way to do it.

Intuitively async/await feels like a good fit for this type of problem but I had difficulty applying it here.

```
function belongTo (user, items) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(items.every((item) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Item.findOne({ owner: user,
          assetID: item.assetid,
          appid: item.appid,
          contextid: item.contextid,
          marketHashName: item.marketHashName
        }).then((item) => {
          if (Object.keys(item).length !== 0) resolve(true)
          else resolve(false)
        }).catch(reject)
      })
    }))
  })
}
```

I'm using the JavaScript Standard style guide.

Comment: You will probably need to use `Promise.all` to wait for all the promises to resolve.

Comment: Is there no way to query the database for all items at once? This would be the first thing I'd try.

Comment: If this code actually does what you want, please rephrase your text to ask for a review and possible better ways to do it. Currently it kind of seems like you're asking us to write code for you, which is off-topic for this site.

Comment: @holroy Thanks for the feedback, I've edited my question to explicitly ask for a review / critique and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it appears that `Item.findOne` already returns a promise. You don't need to wrap it again in a promise. Simply use that same promise as the return value for your `array.every`.

Now as far as I understand your problem, you just need to hit the db for every element in `item` and resolve the promise `belongTo` returns if every element belongs to `user`. I don't think your code will work that way. What will happen is that `belongTo` return a promise will resolve immediately with the value returned by `array.every`.

Next, you don't need to pass `true` or `false` as promise resolution. The fact that it resolved/rejected is enough to tell you that. Also, you don't need to wrap an operation with a promise to create a promise. There's `Promise.resolve()` and `Promise.reject()` that create already resolved/rejected promises.

```
function belongTo (user, items) {
  const pingPromises = items.map(item => Item.findOne({ owner: user,
    assetID: item.assetid,
    appid: item.appid,
    contextid: item.contextid,
    marketHashName: item.marketHashName
  }).then((item) => {
    // Validate result if we should resolve/reject this promise.
    return Object.keys(item).length ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject();
  }));

  // Do not catch. If Item.findOne rejects, let's reuse that rejection.

  // Accepts an array of promises. Returns a promsie that resolves when all
  // promises resolve, rejects when at least one rejects.
  return Promise.all(pingPromises);
}
```

Now even with that code, the operation itself is very inefficient. You might want to consider creating some form of compound query instead and only hit the DB once. Not very familiar with MongoDB, but in MySQL this can easily be done by using multiple conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.

"need to hit the db for every element in item and resolve the promise `belongTo` returns if every element belongs to user" - that's exactly right.

Most of your suggestions make sense right away, especially `Promise.resolve/reject/all()` (which I somehow hadn't heard of until now).

However, I'm stuck on the way you're using `items.every()`. Array.every returns a boolean -- true if every callback on the respective items in the array returns true, false otherwise. It looks like you're calling `Promise.all` with a Boolean -- not an array of Promises.

Comment: @Sports oh... :facepalm: I meant `array.map`.